# Trouble identifying patches of habitat in ArcMap

Tags: gis, arcmap

I’m having some trouble identifying patches of habitat. Ive had some help with this issue before but I cannot get anything to work.

I downloaded the Arcgrid (zipped) from this website http://www.kew.org/gis/projects/mad_veg/datasets_gis.html. I’ve managed to open the data in ArcMap 10.1 and it displays all the habitat types in Madagascar.  I wanted to determine how much of a specific habitat there was (humid forest) and I found that just with the number of pixels.  But obviously that’s the total area that area and in reality is broken and fragmented into thousands of little forests.  I need to find a way to determine how many patches of forest there are and what size they are.

If it helps ill just explain what it is I’m trying to do.  I am studying a species of lemur, and a community needs a minimum 4km2 of forest.  I’m trying to how much viable habitat I left in Madagascar.  The overall area doesn’t give me that because I could be made of patches too small to support a community.  I need a way to find out how much littoral forest there is left in patches over a certain size.

I’m no expert in GIS and someone suggested I run a code python such as

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "Q:\Veggrid"
inZoneData = "vegetation"
zoneField = "Value"
outTable = "zonalgeomout02.dbf" 
processingCellSize = 29
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
outZonalGeometryAsTable = ZonalGeometryAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, "AREA",    processingCellSize)
```

However each time I run this code ArcMap loads for a while and just crashes.  I tried making the cell size smaller but it didn’t make a difference.  Like I I’m not expert and Im not sure what to do.  People have suggested downloading various packages but it’s a university computer and it doesn’t seem to allow it

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.

Try to increase `processingCellSize` (For example: 1000).

Comment: indeed increasing the cell size did prevent ArcMap from crashing.  I got an output table but its not what im looking for.  I seems to be just the total area of each habitat

Comment: You should ask your question in gis.stackexchange.com